# Flutter : TextEditingController Textspan's recognizer raising error on initializing text

Tags: flutter, dart, extend, texteditingcontroller, textspan

Please check this [video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/58595897/151553482-d8c685c1-2681-4872-a743-e00932d1e829.mov).

Here I extend TextEditingController to highlight(also clickable) the keyword "ali". It is working perfectly whenever the user types "ali". But when initializing text to the controller, it is showing a lot of errors. Someone pls help me with how I can resolve this error.

Note: When I initialize the text and remove "recognizer" from "textspan" it is working perfectly without showing any error. I guess this issue is happening because of "recognizer" in the textspan.

here is my code, pls uncomment line number 15 to see the error.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kyubook/utils/utility.dart';

class TexspanTap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TexspanTapState createState() => _TexspanTapState();
}

class _TexspanTapState extends State<TexspanTap> {
  final MyTextEditingcontroller _editingcontroller = MyTextEditingcontroller();

  @override
  void initState() {
    //_editingcontroller.text = "dghali";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _editingcontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _editingcontroller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTextEditingcontroller extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().contains("ali")) {
      final List<InlineSpan> spans = [];

      final int indexOfAli = text.indexOf("ali");

      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(0, indexOfAli)));

      spans.add(
        TextSpan(
            text: text.substring(indexOfAli, indexOfAli + 3),
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTapDown = (final details) {
                commonToast("Touched");
              }),
      );

      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(indexOfAli + 3, text.length)));

      return TextSpan(children: spans, style: style);
    }

    return TextSpan(text: text, style: style);
  }
}
```

**Logs**

```
I/flutter (26328): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26328): The following assertion was thrown building
I/flutter (26328): RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#87b14](state:
I/flutter (26328): RawGestureDetectorState#ede1a(gestures: <none>, excludeFromSemantics: true, behavior: opaque)):
I/flutter (26328): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart': Failed assertion: line 2376 pos 14: 'readOnly &&
I/flutter (26328): !obscureText': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): 
I/flutter (26328): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (26328): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (26328): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (26328):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
I/flutter (26328): 
I/flutter (26328): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (26328):   TextField
I/flutter (26328):   file:///Users/ali/Documents/Flutter/Xcelpros/kb_main_clientside/lib/components/profanity_checker/screen/textspan_tap.dart:32:13
I/flutter (26328): 
I/flutter (26328): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (26328): #2      RenderEditable.describeSemanticsConfiguration (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:2376:14)
I/flutter (26328): #3      RenderObject._semanticsConfiguration (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2525:7)
I/flutter (26328): #4      RenderObject.attach (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1416:34)
I/flutter (26328): #5      RelayoutWhenSystemFontsChangeMixin.attach (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3401:11)
I/flutter (26328): #6      RenderEditable.attach (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:2612:11)
I/flutter (26328): #7      AbstractNode.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart:138:13)
I/flutter (26328): #8      RenderObject.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1274:11)
I/flutter (26328): #9      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.child= (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3022:7)
I/flutter (26328): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6098:18)
I/flutter (26328): #11     RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5758:35)
I/flutter (26328): #12     RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5440:5)
I/flutter (26328): ...     Normal element mounting (92 frames)
I/flutter (26328): #104    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
I/flutter (26328): #105    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3363:18)
I/flutter (26328): #106    _DecorationElement._mountChild (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1591:31)
I/flutter (26328): #107    _DecorationElement.mount (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1604:5)
I/flutter (26328): ...     Normal element mounting (69 frames)
I/flutter (26328): #176    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
I/flutter (26328): #177    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
I/flutter (26328): #178    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
I/flutter (26328): ...     Normal element mounting (34 frames)
I/flutter (26328): #212    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
I/flutter (26328): #213    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
I/flutter (26328): #214    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6232:32)
I/flutter (26328): ...     Normal element mounting (238 frames)
I/flutter (26328): #452    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
I/flutter (26328): #453    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6221:36)
I/flutter (26328): #454    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3363:18)
I/flutter (26328): #455    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5654:32)
I/flutter (26328): #456    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6243:17)
I/flutter (26328): #457    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #458    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #459    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
I/flutter (26328): #460    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #461    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4778:5)
I/flutter (26328): #462    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #463    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #464    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #465    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4922:5)
I/flutter (26328): #466    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #467    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #468    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #469    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4922:5)
I/flutter (26328): #470    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:181:11)
I/flutter (26328): #471    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #472    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
I/flutter (26328): #473    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #474    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #475    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
I/flutter (26328): #476    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #477    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4778:5)
I/flutter (26328): #478    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #479    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
I/flutter (26328): #480    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #481    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6090:14)
I/flutter (26328): #482    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #483    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #484    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #485    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4922:5)
I/flutter (26328): #486    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3350:15)
I/flutter (26328): #487    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4599:16)
I/flutter (26328): #488    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
I/flutter (26328): #489    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
I/flutter (26328): #490    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2582:33)
I/flutter (26328): #491    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:875:21)
I/flutter (26328): #492    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
I/flutter (26328): #493    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
I/flutter (26328): #494    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
I/flutter (26328): #495    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:998:5)
I/flutter (26328): #499    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:163:10)
I/flutter (26328): #500    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:259:5)
I/flutter (26328): #501    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:126:31)
I/flutter (26328): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
I/flutter (26328): 
I/flutter (26328): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: LateInitializationError: Field '_tap@798245603' has not been initialized.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 3 lines
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart': Failed assertion: line 112 pos 12: '_owner != null': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
I/chatty  (26328): uid=10089(com.kyubook.kyubookapp) 1.ui identical 18 lines
I/flutter (26328): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1285 pos 12: 'child.parentData != null': is not true.
```

Comment: instead `TextSpan` why dont you use `WidgetSpan` where you need "clickable" area?

Comment: @pskink WidgetSpan doesn't work with TextEditingController.

Comment: @pskink it is not working, still raising errors.

Comment: @pskink,  could you pls watch this [screenrecord](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLCI91TeYxo8LDqMsqkQcIUO4GnhB-uc/view?usp=sharing). here when I start typing `@` it raises errors. I don't use any other code here.

Comment: @pskink thank you for your effort. however, still, it is not working. i just paste the code that you shared. here pls check this [screenrecord](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLCI91TeYxo8LDqMsqkQcIUO4GnhB-uc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pskink in the web also it is showing error.

Comment: @pskink I'm using Flutter 2.2.2. also tied to latest flutter version, it also showing error

Comment: @pskink actually issue is not with that `trim()`, it is because of using WidgetextSpan in TextEditingController. If you don't mind can you share with me a screen recording of the output of working code?

Answer (score 0):

TextSpan within TextSpan with recognizer only work in RichText widget.
[See here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34931)

So in short, you need RichText in your TextField. But TextFields don't support RichText as of now. You need some package which can make it happen. I found [rich_input](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_input).

Give it a try if this can help you out.

Comment: TextField supports TextSpans - that's why TextEditingController has buildTextSpan method

Comment: @pskink
Yes, TextField supports TextSpans. But as I say it doesn't support RichText. RichText is needed if you want to use nested TextSpan with individual recognizer.

Comment: yes, you are right, i got you wrong... sorry, my fault

Comment: Thank you for responding @AakashKumar. Actually, TextSpan within TextSpan is working perfectly with a recognizer in TextEditingController. The problem is , if we initialize the value while the corresponding Textfield is not rendered, then only it is raising the error. you can see the above mentioned video, when I type keyword "ali", it is highlighting and also clickable, but if I initialize value before rendering the corresponding TextEditingController Textfield, then it is showing errors.


Also, I tried 'rich_input', I think this package doesn't provide the option for 'recognizer'.